# Usage DevExpress Coded UI

Tags: devexpress, coded-ui-tests

I am doing automation testing of a winform and html application with codeduitest and underlying technology uses DevExpress version DevExpressComponents-15.1.6. I see devexpress provides something for codedui only for universal subcscription.

I do not understand what they provide because they do not give exact information how it is used with codedui. I have few questions and I hope someone can answer these questions.
Visual Sudio Codedui does not recognise inside teechart screens, devexpress should provide this ?
VS codedui alread recognize devexpress tables using MSA, what this feature provides extra ?
Should the program alsose be developed by universal subscription ? 
What this devexpress provides actually with DevExpress Coded UI ? 
An extension to codedui library in Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the https://documentation.devexpress.com/CodedUIExtension/11028/Coded-UI-Test-Extension documentation section to learn how to use DevExpress Coded UI Extensions.
In addition check the https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18720/coded-ui-test-extension-faq ticket for frequently asked questions.
Note that you cannot do automation testing of your web app with DevExpres Coded UI Extension.

Not sure what you mean by 'does not recognise in graphic screens', but the extension is designed to write automation tests for DevExpress WinForms controls and forms.

-Should the program alsose be developed by universal subscription ? 
Not really. But you need to have universal subscription to write Coded UI tests.

-What this devexpress provides actually with DevExpress Coded UI ? An extension to codedui library in Visual Studio ?
Not exactly. It is a library or libraries referenced in a Coded Ui project.

Comment: Sorry I edited my post for the confusing parts. So you mean I should show references after installation of devexpress coded ui ? I installed 30-day trial, how can I show references in my coded ui , where are dlls ? And real question, how will I know I use it in codedui ?

Comment: references will be added automatically to the Coded UI Test Project after you created it. Make sure you are using a supported version of Visual Studio IDE: https://documentation.devexpress.com/CodedUIExtension/11032/System-Requirements As you can see, it should be Enterprise, Premium or Ultimate version.